# Delphi Graphics32 relative mouse position (to the layer)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, graphics32

I have a ImgView32, that is anchored to all form margins. The form is maximized.

The bitmap of ImgView is not fixed (it can be of different sizes)

I am trying to draw a line on a transparent layer using ther code from this question:[Drawing lines on layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534892/delphi-graphics32-transparent-layer-draw-line)

Now the problem is that, using that exact code, I can only draw in the top-left corner, like in this image:
[image: drawing after resizing the form (maximize)]

As you can observe, the lines can be drawn only in the left top corner.
If I try to add some value to the Start and End Points, the whole thing goes crazy. So I must find a way to translate the points in such a fashion that, the user will be able to draw only inside of the center rect (visible in the image)

I am out of ideas.

Please help

Here is the whole unit:

```
unit MainU;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs,GR32, GR32_Image, GR32_Layers, GR32_Backends, GR32_PNG, StdCtrls,
  ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    ImgView: TImgView32;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo: TMemo;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Button2: TButton;
    RadioGroup1: TRadioGroup;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ImgViewPaintStage(Sender: TObject; Buffer: TBitmap32;
      StageNum: Cardinal);
    procedure ImgViewResize(Sender: TObject);
 private
    { Private declarations }
    FStartPoint, FEndPoint: TPoint;
    FDrawingLine: boolean;
    bm32: TBitmap32;
    BL : TBitmapLayer;
    FSelection: TPositionedLayer;
 public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure AddLineToLayer;
    procedure AddCircleToLayer;
    procedure SwapBuffers32;
    procedure LayerMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Buttons: TMouseButton;Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure LayerMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Buttons: TMouseButton;Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure LayerMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;X, Y: Integer);
    procedure LayerOnPaint(Sender: TObject; Buffer: TBitmap32);
    procedure SetSelection(Value: TPositionedLayer);
    property Selection: TPositionedLayer read FSelection write SetSelection;

    Procedure SelectGraficLayer(idu:string);
    procedure AddTransparentPNGlayer;

  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
  imwidth: integer;
  imheight: integer;
  OffsX, OffsY: Integer;

const
  penwidth = 3;
  pencolor = clBlue;  // Needs to be a VCL color!

procedure TForm5.AddLineToLayer;
begin
  bm32.Canvas.Pen.Color := pencolor;
  bm32.Canvas.Pen.Width := penwidth;
  bm32.Canvas.MoveTo(FStartPoint.X, FStartPoint.Y);
  bm32.Canvas.LineTo(FEndPoint.X, FEndPoint.Y);
end;

procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: TPoint;
  W, H: Single;
begin
  imwidth := Form5.ImgView.Width;
  imheight := Form5.ImgView.Height;

  with ImgView.PaintStages[0]^ do
  begin
    if Stage = PST_CLEAR_BACKGND then Stage := PST_CUSTOM;
  end;

  bm32 := TBitmap32.Create;
  bm32.DrawMode := dmTransparent;
  bm32.SetSize(imwidth,imheight);
  bm32.Canvas.Pen.Width := penwidth;
  bm32.Canvas.Pen.Color := pencolor;

  with ImgView do
  begin
    Selection := nil;
    Layers.Clear;
    Scale := 1;
    Scaled := True;
    Bitmap.DrawMode := dmTransparent;
    Bitmap.SetSize(imwidth, imheight);
    Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Width := 4;//penwidth;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlue;
    Bitmap.Canvas.FrameRect(Rect(20, 20, imwidth-20, imheight-20));
    Bitmap.Canvas.TextOut(15, 32, 'ImgView');
  end;

  AddTransparentPNGLayer;

  BL := TBitmapLayer.Create(ImgView.Layers);
  try
    BL.Bitmap.DrawMode := dmTransparent;
    BL.Bitmap.SetSize(imwidth,imheight);
    BL.Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Width := penwidth;
    BL.Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := pencolor;
    BL.Location := GR32.FloatRect(0, 0, imwidth, imheight);
    BL.Scaled := False;
    BL.OnMouseDown := LayerMouseDown;
    BL.OnMouseUp := LayerMouseUp;
    BL.OnMouseMove := LayerMouseMove;
    BL.OnPaint := LayerOnPaint;
  except
  Edit3.Text:=IntToStr(BL.Index);
    BL.Free;
    raise;
  end;

  FDrawingLine := false;
  SwapBuffers32;
end;

procedure TForm5.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  bm32.Free;
  BL.Free;
end;

procedure TForm5.ImgViewPaintStage(Sender: TObject; Buffer: TBitmap32;
  StageNum: Cardinal);
const            //0..1
  Colors: array [Boolean] of TColor32 = ($FFFFFFFF, $FFB0B0B0);
var
  R: TRect;
  I, J: Integer;
  OddY: Integer;
  TilesHorz, TilesVert: Integer;
  TileX, TileY: Integer;
  TileHeight, TileWidth: Integer;
begin
  TileHeight := 13;
  TileWidth := 13;

  TilesHorz := Buffer.Width div TileWidth;
  TilesVert := Buffer.Height div TileHeight;
  TileY := 0;

  for J := 0 to TilesVert do
  begin
    TileX := 0;
    OddY := J and $1;
    for I := 0 to TilesHorz do
    begin
      R.Left := TileX;
      R.Top := TileY;
      R.Right := TileX + TileWidth;
      R.Bottom := TileY + TileHeight;
      Buffer.FillRectS(R, Colors[I and $1 = OddY]);
      Inc(TileX, TileWidth);
    end;
    Inc(TileY, TileHeight);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm5.ImgViewResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OffsX := (ImgView.ClientWidth - imwidth) div 2;
  OffsY := (ImgView.ClientHeight - imheight) div 2;
  BL.Location := GR32.FloatRect(OffsX, OffsY, imwidth+OffsX, imheight+OffsY);
end;

procedure TForm5.LayerMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Buttons: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FStartPoint := Point(X-OffsX, Y-OffsY);
  FDrawingLine := true;
end;

procedure TForm5.LayerMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FDrawingLine then
  begin
    SwapBuffers32;
      BL.Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := pencolor;
      BL.Bitmap.Canvas.MoveTo(FStartPoint.X-OffsX, FStartPoint.Y-OffsY);
      BL.Bitmap.Canvas.LineTo(X-OffsX, Y-OffsY);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm5.LayerMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Buttons: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDrawingLine := false;
  FEndPoint := Point(X-OffsX, Y-OffsY);
  AddLineToLayer;
  SwapBuffers32;
end;

procedure TForm5.LayerOnPaint(Sender: TObject; Buffer: TBitmap32);
begin
  SwapBuffers32;
end;

procedure TForm5.SetSelection(Value: TPositionedLayer);
begin
  if Value <> FSelection then
  begin
    FSelection := Value;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm5.SwapBuffers32;
begin
    TransparentBlt(
      BL.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, BL.Bitmap.Width, BL.Bitmap.Height,
      bm32.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, bm32.Width, bm32.Height, clWhite);
end;

procedure TForm5.AddTransparentPNGlayer;
var
  mypng:TPortableNetworkGraphic32;
  B : TBitmapLayer;
  P: TPoint;
  W, H: Single;
begin
      try
        mypng := TPortableNetworkGraphic32.Create;
        mypng.LoadFromFile('C:\Location\Of\ATransparentPNGFile.png');
        B := TBitmapLayer.Create(ImgView.Layers);
        with B do
        try
          mypng.AssignTo(B.Bitmap);
          Bitmap.DrawMode := dmBlend;
          with ImgView.GetViewportRect do
            P := ImgView.ControlToBitmap(GR32.Point((Right + Left) div 2, (Top + Bottom) div 2));
          W := Bitmap.Width * 0.5;
          H := Bitmap.Height * 0.5;
          Location := GR32.FloatRect(P.X - W, P.Y - H, P.X + W, P.Y + H);
          Scaled := True;
          OnMouseDown := LayerMouseDown;
        except
          Free;
          raise;
        end;
        Selection := B;
        Edit3.Text:=IntToStr(B.Index);
      finally
        mypng.Free;
      end;
end;

end.
```

What am I doing wrong? Please test the unit above to see what I mean. Remember to add a ImgView and anchor it to all margins, then at runtime, maximize the form and try to draw the lines...

**EDIT**

In the green image above, there is a rect, more like a square in the middle of it (not very visible) but you can see it if you look closely.

Since my problem might be misunderstood, please take a look at the following image [image]

I need to be able to draw ONLY in the white rectangle (Bitmap) in the middle of the ImgView. I do not know how to explain better.

It is not a solution for me to make the rectangle/Bitmap fit exactly the ImgView, because that is not the point of my project.

Take a look at Paint.net and imagine that my project kind of does the same (except it's not that complex). But the principle is the same: you decide the size of your document/image when you start a new project, then you add different images as layers, you scale and rotate them, and now I want to allow the users to draw lines inside of a special layer (the drawing layer)
But everything happens inside the boundaries of that document size. Like for example in the above image, the size of the document there is A5 (100dpi) scaled at 83%.

So my problem is that I cannot allow the users to draw the lines outside the white rectangle (middle of the screen). So their lines can start in those boundaries and end there.

I know my test unit is not perfectly clean. I pasted some functions used in the main project and quickly removed some parts from them that are not relevant to this example. The AddTransparentPng procedure is there only to allow the testing of adding a transparent image to the ImgView so I can test if the drawing layer is not covering another possible latyer.

(The Scaled property belongs to the layer (B) it's under the 'with B' statement. I removed the With 'ImgView.Bitmap... Location' statement so it would not bother you anymore :) )

Anyway, please do not pay attention to the code that does not affect the drawing of lines. That code is what needs attention.

**EDIT**
If I set the layer's scaled to true (Scaled:=true) then it messes everything up, like in the image bellow:
[image]

I still have to use offsets but a little differently

Thank you

Comment: Increase the size of the TBitmapLayer (using BL.Location) to cover the whole ImgView and increase also the size of the background bitmap (bm23 in the previous question/answer) correspondingly. There's no center rect visible in the image above.

Comment: First of all, stop using `with` statements! You spend more time searching for errors than you save in typing. E.g. in `AddtransparentPNGLayer`, about middle of proc, the line `with ImgView.Bitmap do Location := GR32.Floatrect(...);`, who's property do you think `Location`is? It is *NOT* a property of `ImgView.Bitmap`! It's a property of `B` that you refer to in the statement `with B do ...`, so why did you write `with ImgView.Bitmap do`? Another one, who's property is `Scaled` on the next line? It is a property of Form5! It sounds harsch, but really: Remove all `with` statements from the code.

Comment: Further, just in case, there's nothing else in the statement `with ImgView.Bitmap do` related to the bitmap.

Comment: Sorry, these procedures are taken from a larger project that does more than what happens in the test unit and I did not clean them properly before posting the unit. I am in a hurry when I post these question because I do not want to lose your attention (there are a lot of questions that do not receive comments at all so if I get an experts attention I try to keep it). But that is not the problem that makes the unit not work properly

Comment: It is not a solution for me. I might have explained my problem wrongly. Please check the question for an EDIT with more images and explanations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Error one**

In LayerMouseMove() you subtract OffsX and OffsY from FStartPoint in BL.Bitmap.Canvas.MoveTo(). FStartPoint was already adjusted in LayerMouseDown(). I told you to "In the three Mouse procs adjust the X and Y arguments only to become X-OffsX and Y-OffsY." Note `arguments only` Here's LayerMouseMove() corrected:

```
procedure TForm5.LayerMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FDrawingLine then
  begin
    SwapBuffers32;
      BL.Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := pencolor;
//      BL.Bitmap.Canvas.MoveTo(FStartPoint.X-OffsX, FStartPoint.Y-OffsY);
      BL.Bitmap.Canvas.MoveTo(FStartPoint.X, FStartPoint.Y);
      BL.Bitmap.Canvas.LineTo(X-OffsX, Y-OffsY);
  end;
end;
```

**Error two**

I also told you to add `if FDrawingLine then ...` condition to LayerMouseUp() to avoid spurious line when the mouse down happens outside of the layer, but mouse up occurs inside. The corrected LayerMouseUp():

```
procedure TForm5.LayerMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Buttons: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if FDrawingLine then
  begin
    FDrawingLine := false;
    FEndPoint := Point(X-OffsX, Y-OffsY);
    AddLineToLayer;
    SwapBuffers32;
  end;
end;
```

**Error three**

The posted code does not perform as your first image shows. The image looks like you would have outcommented the line `BL.Location := ...` in ImgViewResize(). Possibly you did this because of `Error one`. Anyway, with ImgViewResize as follows and the other corrections above I get the result as shown in the picture that follows.

```
procedure TForm5.ImgViewResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // centering the drawing area
  OffsX := (ImgView.ClientWidth - imwidth) div 2;
  OffsY := (ImgView.ClientHeight - imheight) div 2;
  BL.Location := GR32.FloatRect(OffsX, OffsY, imwidth+OffsX, imheight+OffsY);
end;
```

Variables `imwidth` and `imheight` defines the size of the drawing area. If you change these you need to recalculate `OffsX` and `OffsY` and you need to resize the backbuffer `bm32` as well.

[image]

The lines in the corners indicate the extent of the drawing area (defined by imwidth and imheight) in the middle of the window. It stays the same also when the window is maximized.

Comment: Thank you. OnMouseUp works either way, but thanks anyway. I of course will award you this question because my code is based on your previous answers.

Comment: I am busy with my work right now. I return to the scaling and error later today.

Comment: Could you take a look at this question too please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279408/delphi-graphics32-edit-layer-erase-parts-of-tbitmap32-layer I wonder if I can make an eraser for my transparent drawing layer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. Here is the final (relevant) code:

```
procedure TForm5.ImgViewResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OffsX := (ImgView.ClientWidth - imwidth) div 2;
  OffsY := (ImgView.ClientHeight - imheight) div 2;
  BL.Location := GR32.FloatRect(OffsX, OffsY, imwidth+OffsX, imheight+OffsY);
end;

procedure TForm5.SwapBuffers32;
begin
    TransparentBlt(
      BL.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, BL.Bitmap.Width, BL.Bitmap.Height,
      bm32.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, bm32.Width, bm32.Height, clWhite);
end;


procedure TForm5.LayerMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Buttons: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FStartPoint := Point(X-OffsX, Y-OffsY);
  FDrawingLine := true;
end;

procedure TForm5.LayerMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FDrawingLine then
  begin
    SwapBuffers32;
      BL.Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := pencolor;
      BL.Bitmap.Canvas.MoveTo(FStartPoint.X, FStartPoint.Y);
      BL.Bitmap.Canvas.LineTo(X-OffsX, Y-OffsY);
  end;
end;


procedure TForm5.LayerMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Buttons: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDrawingLine := false;
  FEndPoint := Point(X-OffsX, Y-OffsY);
  AddLineToLayer;
  SwapBuffers32;
end;

procedure TForm5.LayerOnPaint(Sender: TObject; Buffer: TBitmap32);
begin
  SwapBuffers32;
end;

procedure TForm5.AddLineToLayer;
begin
  bm32.Canvas.Pen.Color := pencolor;
  bm32.Canvas.Pen.Width := penwidth;
  bm32.Canvas.MoveTo(FStartPoint.X, FStartPoint.Y);
  bm32.Canvas.LineTo(FEndPoint.X, FEndPoint.Y);
end;
```

With this code, everything works as expected. The drawing of lines can only happen within the boundaries

Thank you

Comment: It seems you posted while I was preparing my answer. You may want to review LayerMouseUp

Comment: :) probably. Please check my comment to your answer